# C++ making a console: binding a function

Tags: c++, function, console

I am currently working on creating a console in c++. I have created a class to help link variables and functions in code to variables and functions in the console.

I currently have it set where if I have a variable in code, I can redefine it under the new class and it will be visible to the console. The variable in code still behaves the same as before.

Example:

`float var = 1.0;`

can be redefined as

`ConsoleVar var("myVariable")<float> = 1.0;`

var is the variable name in the code and myVariable is the name that you use to access it in the terminal

My question is:

How can I bind a function, or more specifically, detect the number and type of the arguments.
I know that I can template the `ConsoleVar` class to a `void *` type to store a function but is there a way for me to auto detect the return type, number of arguments and type of arguments? I am planning on shipping this in a library so I am going for ease of use. If this is possible, I would really like to know (I'll even do assembly if needed) otherwise I have some ideas on how to implement it.

EDIT: So I think that I have a solution but I have a question... Is it possible to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. Not like varargs.

For instance: I recieve 3 args from the command line, now I execute the function

`func(arg[1], arg[2], arg[3])`

Is it possible to send a variable number of arguments?

Comment: Do you know of any restrictions for your function types?  What would you want `int printf( const char *, ... )` to detect?

Comment: Only the basic C types and if possible, user defined classes. No variable length functions.

Comment: There is no way from a `void*` to the type information. It's also far from clear what you mean with your question. For example, binding a function is something you can do with e.g. Boost.Bind, but if you want to know something about that the use case (writing a "console", whatever it is you mean with that) is irrelevant. Similarly, "template the ConsoleVar class to a void*" - I'm really not sure what you mean. Finally, shouldn't that be  `ConsoleVar<float> var("myVariable", 1.0);`? I can't imagine any definition of ConsoleVar that would allow your code to compile...

Comment: What would you do with your function even if you did know the type signature?  Are you expecting the console to be able to invoke it?

Comment: @doomster I use an operator overload to assign the number to tho class

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, the console is going to invoke it. Knowing the return and argument types will allow me to have some form of error handling.

Comment: @Chase: I suggest you pay careful attention to `IDispatch::Invoke` (and in fact all of `IDispatch`) as a mechanism that allows polymorphic storage of objects and their methods, in a manner that allows discovery and invocation from scripting languages.  You can't just pass the function call as a string, if you want to allow arguments to be arbitrary expressions (well you could but the function wrapper would have to call back into the engine).  But you do need some generic way of expressing the arguments and a type-aware wrapper.

Comment: Calling a function pointer that's been cast to a different type is both impractical and causes undefined behavior.  Use wrappers to bring all your functions to a common interface (arguments passed in an array, basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will do the job.

```
#include <typeinfo>    

// Function with 0 parameters
template< typename Ret >
void examine_function( Ret (*func)() )
{
    std::cout << typeinfo(Ret).name() << std::endl;
}

// Function with 1 parameters
template< typename Ret, typename Param1 >
void examine_function( Ret (*func)(Param1) )
{
    std::cout << typeinfo(Ret).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeinfo(Param1).name() << std::endl;
}

// Function with 2 parameters
template< typename Ret, typename Param1, typename Param2 >
void examine_function( Ret (*func)(Param1, Param2) )
{
    std::cout << typeinfo(Ret).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeinfo(Param1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeinfo(Param2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: ... and then not cast it to a `void*` at all.  Casting pointers between data and functions is undefined behavior.

Comment: I think I have a solution! I can Post the code when I'm done if anyone is interested